# How do I create an Expression for a Property for reference and value types?

Tags: c#, reflection, linq-expressions

I'm trying to create expressions at runtime to pass to a 3rd party API, which has a signature of 
`Expression<Func<T, object>>`. Below is what I have so far. This works fine for reference types, but value types result with an exception(3rd line).

> Expression of type 'System.Boolean' cannot be used for return type
>   'System.Object'

I'm assuming this is due to a boxing issue, which I'm not dealing with.

I have attempted to add `Expression.TypeAs(property, typeof(object))`, but the API wont accept/parse this input, as it generates `obj=> (obj.Foo As Object)` .

Anyone have any ideas on how I can create an expression which matches the required signature for any type?

```
// must be in the form of 'obj => obj.Foo', or the API wont parse
private static Expression<Func<T, object>> CreatePropertyExpression(PropertyInfo propertyInfo)
{
   var instanceParam = Expression.Parameter(propertyInfo.DeclaringType, "obj");
   var property = Expression.Property(instanceParam, propertyInfo);
   var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>(property, instanceParam); // kaboom

   return (Expression<Func<T, object>>)lambda;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a cast/convert:

```
return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>(
    Expression.Convert(property, typeof(object)), instanceParam);
```